# Is there any way to split a CONST char * with a delimiter into an array?

Tags: c, split, c-strings, function-definition

I'm trying to split a given string (input) into an array of elements. Here is my code:

```
char *buff = save_to_buff(); // save the input
int token_count = 1;
for(int i = 0; buff[i] != '\0';i++)
{
    if(buff[i] == ' ')
    {
        token_count++;
    }
}
char *token = strtok(buff, " ");
char *arr[token_count];

for(int i = 0;token != NULL;i++)
{
    arr[i] = token;
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
}
for(int i = 0; i < token_count;i++)
{
    printf("%s ", arr[i]);
}
```

It works, however I need to make a function char **parse_cmdline(const char *cmdline) which splits the buff(cmdline) in this case into an array, but how can I do that if it is even possible? I either get a warning that the 'const' qualifier is discared or an error. Is there any way?

Comment: Command line arguments are not `const` qualified. Are you using the correct declaration of `main`?

Comment: @Neil I'm using "int main(int argc, char *argv[])"

Comment: @User_Not_Found I can suggest a solution if you will mark my answer as the best answer.:)

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but then you are adding constness in your `parse_cmdline`. Since you explicitly modify the parameter, it doesn't make sense for it to be `const`. Just drop that.

Comment: @User_Not_Found You selected a bad approach.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow well sure I can give you that and I am working with a grader, not my choice :/

Comment: @User_Not_Found Bro, do you promise? If so then I will publish my answer through a minute.:)

Comment: @vlad yeah I'll upvote it and give you the checkmark

Comment: @User_Not_Found Well. Wait a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split the function into two functions.

The first one will return the number of tokens in a given string. Using the return value of the function you can allocate an array of pointers the number of elements of which is equal to the number of tokens in the given string plus one. That is the array of tokens will end with a null pointer.

The second function will fill the provided array with tokens of the given string.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

size_t count_tokens( const char *s1, const char *s2 )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while (*s1)
    {
        s1 += strspn( s1, s2 );

        if (*s1)
        {
            ++n;
            s1 += strcspn( s1, s2 );
        }
    }

    return n;
}

size_t get_tokens( char **s1, const char *s2, const char *s3 )
{
    size_t n = 0;

    while (*s2)
    {
        s2 += strspn( s2, s3 );
        
        if (*s2)
        {
            ++n;

            const char *p = s2;
            s2 += strcspn( s2, s3 );

            size_t len = s2 - p;
            *s1 = malloc( len + 1 );

            if (*s1)
            {
                memcpy( *s1, p, len );
                ( *s1 )[len] = '\0';
            }

            ++s1;
        }
    }

    *s1 = NULL;

    return n;
}


int main( void )
{
    const char *s1 = "Hello World!";

    size_t n = count_tokens( s1, " " );

    printf( "%zu\n", n );

    char **p = malloc( ( n + 1 ) * sizeof( char * ) );

    get_tokens( p, s1, " " );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ )
    {
        if ( p[i] ) puts( p[i] );
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        free( p[i] );
    }

    free( p );
}
```

The program output is

```
2
Hello
World!
```

As a delimiter of tokens you can pass any string to the functions as for example `" \t\n'`.

Comment: So I don't actually use char **parse_cmdline(const char *cmdline)  and just split its function into two other functions?

Comment: @User_Not_Found Yes, it is better to split the function into two functions. Also it is more flexible when a string with delimiters is passed by the user of the functions.

Comment: @User_Not_Found You may name the functions as you like.

Comment: Okay, thanks but with this method is there any way to maybe make the "char **parse_cmdline(const char *cmdline)" a third function or something because I think the grader I'm working with checks for the function itself to exist and maybe combine the two function in the third one instead of the main()?

Comment: @User_Not_Found I do not know what is "grader"  but this function declaration char **parse_cmdline(const char *cmdline) is not good. For example it does not accept a string with delimiters. Also it is unknown how many tokens the passed string has. Nevertheless you can combine the two shown function as one function that at first determines the number of tokens and then within itself allocates an array of pointers.

Comment: Okay here's what I tried:  So I put the size_t n and char **p in "char **parse_cmdline" and also called the get_tokens() func after and then returned p and called it in main: "char **result = parse_cmdline(s1);" and then freed result like you did p in your last loop and there is a memory leak again. Any idea how to fix this? (I also defined n again in main to free result)

Comment: @User_Not_Found There is no memory leaks in the code I showed. It seems it is a problem of your code that I do not know.

Comment: @Vlad_from_Moscow Ok can you take a look at this? https://pastebin.com/hUiqzUJk

Comment: @User_Not_Found I will be at home very late. More probably I will see the link tomorrow in the morning.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow the only problem is that you have n+1 allocations and iterate the string at least 3 times. Not too efficient.

Comment: @User_Not_Found You need also to free the memory pointed to by the pointer result after the for loop free( result );

Answer (score 1):

`const` objects cannot be modified. It is undefined behaviour. You need to make a modifiable copy of the string before you use `strtok`.

```
char **split(const char *restrict str, const char *restrict delim)
{
    char **result = NULL;
    char *copy;
    size_t ntokensLen;
    if(str && delim && *str && *delim)
    {
        copy = malloc(ntokensLen = strlen(str + 1));
        if(copy)
        {
            char *token;
            
            memcpy(copy, str, ntokensLen + 1);
            ntokensLen = 0;
            token = strtok(copy, delim);

            if(!token) free(copy); 
   
            while(token) 
            {   
                char **tmp;
                tmp = realloc(result, (ntokensLen + 2) * sizeof(*tmp));
                if(!tmp) { /* error hanling */}
                result = tmp;
                result[ntokensLen] = token;
                result[ntokensLen + 1] = NULL;
                token = strtok(NULL, delim);
                ntokensLen++;
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char *str = "This!is string ^to test...";

    char **result = split(str, "! ^.");
    size_t cnt = 0;

    while(result[cnt])
    {
        printf("result[%zu] = `%s`\n", cnt, result[cnt]);
        cnt++;
    }
    // how to free? 
    free(result[0]);
    free(result);
}
```

### EDIT:

Added How to free. `result` holds the reference to `realloc`ed memory, `result[0]` to `malloc`ed.

`result` is NULL pointer terminated.

Other split versions:

```
char **mystrtok(const char *str, const char *del, int alowempty)
{
  char **result = NULL;
  const char *end = str;
  size_t size = 0;
  int extrachar;

  while(*end)
  {
    if((extrachar = !!strchr(del, *end)) || !*(end + 1))
    {
        /* add temp variable and malloc / realloc checks */
        /* free allocated memory on error */
        if(!(!alowempty && !(end - str)))
        {
            extrachar = !extrachar * !*(end + 1);
            result = realloc(result, (++size + 1) * sizeof(*result));
            result[size] = NULL;
            result[size -1] = malloc(end - str + 1 + extrachar);
            strncpy(result[size -1], str, end - str + extrachar);
            result[size -1][end - str + extrachar] = 0;
        }
        str = end + 1;
    }
    end++;
  }
  return result;
}
```

double pointer supplied by the caller

```
char **split(char **argv, int *argc, const char *str, const char *delimiter, int allowempty)
{
    char *string = malloc(strlen(str + 1));
    strcpy(string, str);
    *argc = 0;
    do
    {
        if(*string && (!strchr(delimiter, *string) || allowempty))
        {
            argv[(*argc)++] = string;
        }
        while(*string && !strchr(delimiter, *string)) string++;
        if(*string) *string++ = 0;
        if(!allowempty) 
            while(*string && strchr(delimiter, *string)) string++;
    }while(*string);
    return argv;
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you very much!

Comment: How do you free `copy`?

Comment: How do I free tmp and copy because there's a memory leak?

Comment: you do not have to as it assigned to the result if realloc was OK. If not the result is the same as before. You need only to free return value of the function. No leak

Comment: I tried to free the result in main() but when I valgrind the program it finds 2 memory leaks in the function itself with malloc and realloc

Comment: @User_Not_Found `free(result[0]);
    free(result);` I do not know do you do not understand. The only possible leak is when there are no delimiters in the string. Corrected.